# Neutral Messaging Language and XML

Tags: xml, networking

I have a question, quite desperate at the moment, because i couldn't find any proper info on the internet.

Do you some how know the connection of NML and XML. I know that we can send XML messages in client and server architecture, for example, but is there any example of how NML is used?
I know it is like a protocol, organises the communication between server-client, etc.
Is there any chance that XML messages can be converted to NML and sent in NML format, and on the different side once the message is received, it is converted back to XML again?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either use XML or NML and not convert between the two.

Judging by the paper in the first link:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=neutral+messaging+language&aq=2&oq=neutral+mess&aqi=g3g-m7

The two are completely different - one is file format, another is API, one is self-documenting and another is very tight.

Just read the comparison of NML and COBRA (XML-based):

NML is designed to operate in a distributed real-time environment. By contrast,
CORBA works well in a totally distributed environment where applications communicate
across a network, but it fails to achieve success in a hard real-time environment.

It seems to me that you would chose one or another depending on the design goals.

Comment: oh, thanks for the answer, yeah, i saw the document, but didnt know COBRA was xml based. i also thought, that it is impossible to use both, but after i did a further research in the internet i found this: "nml support for xml" document: http://www.isd.mel.nist.gov/projects/rcslib/NML_XML.html
hope it will help

Comment: Well, I am sure there is support for it ... but it sort of defeats the fast and real time approach.

Comment: we found a soulution, you were absolutely right, we are going to use both indeentdently, generate xml file for outputs, and use nml for messages.